# Postgresql 9.5 has_database_privilege always returning True

Tags: postgresql

The behavior is under going in postgresql version 9.5.

I'm trying to use the has_database_privilege function to check whether a user is allowed to connect to the database, but it always returns true. Even after running a revoke all privileges.

```
select * from has_database_privilege('tests', 'db_test', 'connect');
-- expected: true
-- return: true

-- Removing connection permission only.
revoke connect on database db_test from tests;

select * from has_database_privilege('tests', 'db_test', 'connect');
-- expected: false
-- return: true

-- Removing all permissions.
revoke all privileges on database db_test from tests;

select * from has_database_privilege('tests', 'db_test', 'connect');
-- expected: false
-- return: true
```

I am doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: You are revoking the right to connect to `sigma_db_test` but you test for the database `db_test`

Comment: **Typo**, sorry! Now it's right

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto, this is an internal function.